# VBS Script tab not null

Tags: windows, scripting, vbscript

Earlier I have made a script to grab certain lines from a tabbed delimited text file, first row with each of the following rows into its own .txt file. (so these .txt files are only 2 rows of text)

Then it would move each .txt file by what text it found in the given tab in this case it was (1)(3) (second row - forth tab)

here is the code for the first part...

```
Call TwoDimensionArrayTest

Sub TwoDimensionArrayTest

Dim fso
 Dim oFile
 Dim arrline
 Dim arrItem
 Dim i
 Dim arrMain()
 Dim sFileLocation, strResults

 Const forReading = 1

strFolder = "\\nas001\Production\RxCut\In Design Implementation\build\" '"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each objFile In objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder).Files
 If Right(LCase(objFile.Name), 4) = LCase(".txt") Then

 ''# The file contains on each line:
 ''# Text1 (tab) Text2 (tab) Text3 (tab) Text4
 ''# Text5 (tab) Text6 (tab) Text7 (tab) Text8
 ''# etc etc

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  sFileLocation = objFile.Name

  Set oFile = fso.OpenTextFile(objFile.Name, forReading, False)

 Do While oFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
  strResults = oFile.ReadAll
 Loop

 ''# Close the file
 oFile.Close

''# Release the object from memory
 Set oFile = Nothing

''# Return the contents of the file if not Empty
 If Trim(strResults) <> "" Then

  ''# Create an Array of the Text File
  arrline = Split(strResults, vbNewLine)
 End If

 For i = 0 To UBound(arrline)
  If arrline(i) = "" Then
   ''# checks for a blank line at the end of stream
   Exit For
  End If 

  ReDim Preserve arrMain(i)

   arrMain(i) = Split(arrline(i), vbTab)

 Next

      fso.MoveFile sFileLocation, arrMain(1)(3) & ".txt"
 End If 
 Next
End Sub ''# TwoDimensionArrayTest
```

Now moving on to the next part...

ok I have a tabbed delimited text file and in this file we have specified on first row 5th tab co-brand, 6th tab tri-brand, and 7th generic.

second row we have the directory path to whichever it maybe either co-brand, tri-brand or generic.

What I want to be able to do is move a given file we can call "group.txt" to either of those co-brand, tri-brand, or generic directories depending upon which field is NOT NULL.

How can I accomplish this? Would be nice to just be able to incorporate this into the last script towards the end where specified:

```
  fso.MoveFile sFileLocation, arrMain(1)(3) & ".txt"
```

of course would depend from here what I mentioned above about the NOT NULL field.

Any help is greatly appreciated,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

my guess is something like this at the end (maybe):

If not isNull(Rs("arrMain(1)(4)")) Then

Set sDirectory = "/co-brand"

End If

If not isNull(Rs("arrMain(1)(5)")) Then

Set sDirectory = "/tri-brand"

End If

If not isNull(Rs("arrMain(1)(6)")) Then

Set sDirectory = "/generic"

End If

```
  fso.MoveFile sFileLocation, sDirectory, arrMain(1)(3) & ".txt"
```